# PostgreSQL how to count records in a recursive query

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I want to count all descendant of node

```
with recursive t as (
  select a.id, 0 cntr from a 
   where parent_id = 12 union all
  select a.id, cntr + 1 from t 
  join a on a.parent_id = t.id 
   where cntr <= 100
)

select * from t
```

But this example get depth count.
I want to get all descendant different levels, and limit it. Result like this:

```
12, 0
13, 1
17, 2
...
232, 100
```

Table very big, select * and count it - not an option
How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. You need to retain the id as the child to join to the parent in your recursive term (you don't have to SELECT it in the end, but it needs to be present for your join). When you select, you want a count of records for each `id`, your counter is really more of a `depth`, but if your hierarchy isn't linear (like it branches out) then `depth` doesn't quite get what you want.

```
with recursive t as (
  select ae.id, ae.id as child_id, 0 cntr 
  from a 
  where parent_id = 12 
  union all
  select t.id, a.id, cntr + 1 from t 
  join a on a.parent_id = t.child_id 
  where cntr <= 100
)

select id, count(*) from t group by id
```

If depth or count isn't what you are after, perhaps it's just a row_number of the descendant nodes? Change that select to:

```
select child_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Child_Id) FROM t;
```

Comment: I don't understand how that update changes anything. This recursive statement can give you both depth and/or count-of-descendant nodes depending on what you are after. Please share some sample data and your desired result from that small sample for clarity.

Comment: I want to get 100 records - descendants of my node, nombered like my example (depth should not affect)

Comment: But what does the numbering mean then? Why would one node be 1 and another 50 if not depth? Should they just be numbered arbitrarily or based on some order (perhaps ordered by the id from 1 to 100)?

Comment: numbered arbitrarily or perhaps ordered by the id from 1 to 100 - both options work for me